# Parsing Error: Unexpected Token In React. It keeps reoccurring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a website with React and it's throwing me a parsing error, but I don't see what's wrong with it. What I'm doing in the code is displaying a table list of users for a specific organization.

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import { Users } from '../../../data/cp/Directory.data';

class OrgsView extends Component {
     render() {
          return (
                <div id='orgViewContent'>
                     <Table striped>
                         <Table.Body>
                              {
                                   Users.map(function(user) {
                                        return ((user.organization === this.props.id) &&
                                        (
                                             <Table.Row className='userListItem' id={user.id}>
                                                  <Table.Cell className='userItemName'><Link to={'directory?id=' + user.id + '&q=users'}>{user.name}</Link></Table.Cell>
                                                  <Table.Cell className='userItemStatus' collapsing>{user.status}</Table.Cell>
                                                  <Table.Cell className='userItemCreateDate' collapsing>{user.createdDate}</Table.Cell>
                                             </Table.Row>
                                        ));
                                   }, this)
                              }
                         </Table.Body>
                    </Table>
                 </div>
          );
     }
}

export default OrgsView;
```

**The error it's giving me**

```
Line 70:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

70 |  '&q=users'}>{user.name}</Link></Table.Cell>
                             ^
```

The error is pointing at the `<` of `</Link>`

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: This is parsing correctly for me. What are you using as your tooling to parse the jsx?

Comment: could you possibly be using a non-standard keyboard / language?

Comment: @azium The jsx is parsed with Babel. This issue occurs randomly. Sometimes it's with other pieces of code and when I exit the program in the terminal and run the application again with "npm start", the issue goes away and later comes back. I'm using a regular Macbook keyboard in English language.

Comment: pretty mysterious i must say. it almost sounds like someone is pranking you and replacing legal characters with illegal ones that look the same. it's an old trick we used to play on each other, hopefully that's not the case. My best recommendation is to integrate https://prettier.io into your editor. that should help to eliminate some surface areas of the problem